# Determine the rank of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, differential

The problem

Let $p$ be defined by

$$ \begin{array}{c r c l} 
p : & \mathbb{R}^2 & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}^3 \\
& (\theta,\phi) & \mapsto & \left( \frac{\cos \phi}{\cosh \theta},\frac{\sin \phi}{\cosh \theta},\tanh \theta \right)
\end{array} $$

Show that $p$ is an immersion on the sphere s.t $(\theta,\phi)$ is not onto the poles.

My works

I know I have to prove that the differential of $p$ is injective. Then, I show that the jacobian matrix of $p$ is

$$ \mathrm{Jac}_{(\theta,\phi)}(p) = \left( \begin{array}{c c}
- \frac{\cos \phi \sinh \theta}{\cosh^2 \theta} & - \frac{\sin \phi }{\cosh \theta} \\
 - \frac{\cos \phi \sinh \theta}{\cosh^2 \theta} & \frac{\cos \phi }{\cosh \theta} \\
 \frac{1}{\cosh^2 \theta} & 0 \\
\end{array} \right) $$

Next, I have to find that the rank of this jacobian matrix is equal to $0$. But I don't know how to do it. Do we have to determine the determinant? or should I show that the jacobian matrix is equal to $(0,0,0)$ if and only if $(\theta,\phi) = (0,0)$?

Thank you

Comment: Determinants are only defined for square matrices. Since this matrix is rectangular it doesn't have an determinant. Row reduction is a common method to discover the rank of a rectangular matrix.

Comment: I see. Row reduction with Gauss reduction method. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cosh$ is everywhere nonzero, so calling the two columns $v_1$ and $v_2$, if we have
$$
av_1 + bv_2 = 0,
$$
then $\frac{a}{\cosh^2 \theta} + b \cdot 0 = 0$, so $a = 0$. Now look at $v_2$: its first two entries are just $(-\sin \phi, \cos \phi)$, multiplied by a nonzero number. These can never be simultaneously zero because $\sin^2 \phi + \cos^2 \phi = 1$ for all $\phi$.

In short, if a combination of the columns is zero, then the coefficients are both zero; hence the columns are linearly independent, hence the rank is $2$. That's what you need to show the function's an immersion. (Note that I did *not* show that the rank of the Jacobian is zero, as you asked, because (a) it's false, and (b) it's not what's needed anyhow.)

Comment: I understand, the rank is 2 because $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent (2 vectors). I have a question, why do you have the following implication $$ av_1 + bv_2 = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{a}{\cosh^2 \theta} + b \cdot 0 = 0 $$

Comment: Look at the third entry of $av_1 + bv_2$, which must be zero.